# Load JSON Data after JSON data is created with PHP in Objective C

Tags: php, objective-c, json, tableview

I save data in the database, and when someone opens a view (iPhone application), then I create the JSON by calling the .php script that is saved on the server.

After that I read the JSON and load it in the tableview.

But sometimes the tableview is empty, and this is caused of the fact that the .php script isn't done with creating the JSON, so the view can't load anything.

This is the case:

1. Open view
2. Execute .php-script (serverside)
3. Php script creates JSON
4. View loads the created JSON << `Here it goes sometime wrong, the JSON isn't done creating, so the tableview is empty`

This is what I am doing in Objective C:

```
    [self createJSON];   //calls the php file that creates the JSON
    [self loadJSON];   //loads the JSON and puts it in a NSMutableArray
    [self.tableView reloadData]; //Reloads the Tableview with the JSON Data
```

I want to avoid the tableview being empty when the php script isn't done with creating.

How would you guys solve this? I need something that waits until the php script is done, so the JSON data can be load in the tableview.

Answer (score 0):

You would generally have a completion block or something similar that will be called when the php is done creating the JSON.  You would place the loadJSON and reloadData in that.

```
[self createJSONWithCompletionBlock: ^{
  [self loadJSON];
  [self.tableView reloadData];
}];
```

Or something similar.